# Chess software that shows current score

Tags: software, training

When playing computer chess software I find myself wondering "who's winning right now according to the computer?". For example: I make a bad move but I don't realize it yet - but the computer looking 5 moves ahead immediately realizes that I've made a terrible mistake.

The computer AI must have this information internally (it's own evaluation of the current board position).  Is there an example of a computer chess game that shows this (ideally for iPhone so I can teach myself while on the train)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One chess program with the feature you are looking for is the Shredder app (available on both IOS and Android for a small-ish fee). It has a dial-like control under the board that swings left or right depending on who is winning, but without telling you what the next best move is.

Comment: I've downloaded it and I agree it's great! It even just told me "I don't think your last move was very good" - exactly what I'm looking for!

Answer (score 3):

Disclaimer: I wrote SmallFish.

I would recommend SmallFish on iOS. It's free, and it has the most powerful engine on iOS. It has very advanced analysis feature, look at the screenshot

[image]

[image]

Comment: It looks like it could be amazing but on my iphone seems to freeze on "Tutorial follow the instructions". Swiping etc don't work.

Comment: It's started working and looks incredible but needs a few tweaks I think: eg should default to computer plays black, don't have 5 minute time limit to start etc.